# Why I can't upload a 4k video to phpvibe?

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, upload, segmentation-fault, bad-request

So I trying to playing with Google VM tools and Phpvibe.
My chalange is, you can upload any video whatever you want, to the site and after that the server is convert to the optimal format, so you can play the video.
I set everything for this page can be work, like ioncube, gd libery, etc (the rest is listed [in here](http://www.phpvibe.com/requirements/)), and I also done with this settings:
http://www.phpvibe.com/cms/phpvibe-uploads/
Still, when I trying to upload a 4k video (resolution:3840x2160), which size is 2,27Gb, I get a error on the page:

> "Bad Response: 0 Upload Failed."

I tryed this video upload to a different server, which has 8 core procesor, and 8GB-ram, and that's also dosen't work, same error just like before.
Only thing what I have is a  segmentation fault on apache errorr log, but I realy don't understand what can I do with it.
This is what excatly on erorr log:

> [Tue Apr 26 13:04:15 2016] [notice]
> child pid 20039 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

I'm fully new bie in this world and I need a more exprected person for I can solve this problem, because I starting lost in articles on Google.

Comment: Did you ensure the video file adhered exactly to a support format?

Comment: @Chopper3 it's a simple mp4 video with h264 codec, it's need to be work

Comment: @Chopper3 but this more likely a server fault, the file can't reach the uploaded status.

Comment: You should probably contact their support.

Comment: Obvisely this is apache error, they can't help about this.

Comment: Did you tweak your php.ini file? The default settings are very small. http://www.phpvibe.com/cms/phpvibe-uploads/

Comment: @NathanC Like I said on my question, I already did.

Comment: @Neo Actually, I'm pretty sure that's a PHP segmentation fault. A note to their support along the lines of "I'm getting a segmentation fault on Apache 2.x, PHP 5.x, is this a known issue?" would be well-advised.

Comment: @ceejayoz This happend before, you can see the answer, just like I said:
http://www.phpvibe.com/forum/206/segmentation-fault-in-apache/msg21149/#msg21149

http://www.phpvibe.com/forum/206/site-shut-down/msg26293/#msg26293

Comment: The developer's claims there there "*You can look at them, php errors have file and line, and different syntax. These are clearly apache errors, which I can't touch script side, maybe an upgrade to a server module went bad...this is for an server administrator to notice and fix, not put blame on scripts because it's easier.*" are false. Segmentation faults don't have a file or line number because of their nature, but PHP segfaults look **exactly** like those lines.

Comment: What version of PHP are you on?

Comment: @ceejayoz now you understand why I'm trouble, if the developer said this is a server fault, who am I, a simple user, and starter webadmin for I I question this.
PHP Version 5.4.45-0+deb7u2(Based on `phpinfo()`)

Comment: PHP 5.4 was end-of-lifed seven months ago and is now dangerously insecure as a result. You should upgrade it and see if that resolves your issue. http://php.net/eol.php

Comment: @ceejayoz I can't look the requirements.
http://www.phpvibe.com/requirements/

Comment: It says "5.3+". If the script won't work on a supported version of PHP, you should consider a different script.

Comment: @ceejayoz and it's also sayed, 5.4 version is preferated.
Anyway I pushed a apt-get update command and this is the lataest for me